# Создание типов на основании XML

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, есть некоторая XML конфигурация, в которой можно указать тип и параметры для конструктора и хотелось бы на основании этого создавать некоторый объект.

Подскажите, выбирать конструктор мне придется ручками, анализируя XML или .NET имеет что-то готовое для этой задачи?

Или есть какой-то другой путь, которым я могу пойти?

Смысл в том, что бы редактируя конфигурацию, можно было менять поведение службы, создавая различные объекты.

Comment: Стандартными способами - нельзя. Структура вашего xml-файла может быть разной. Напишите свою фабрику для создания объектов. Для удобства используйте linq to xml.

Comment: Хотелось бы больше информации, какие именно классы. Если они имеют общего предка, то кое-что можно сделать автоматически.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, я пока на стадии планирования структуры. Скорее всего, будет общий предок.

Comment: Мне кажется оптимальным вариантом будет составить xsd схему, на основании схемы сгенерировать C# типы утилитой `xsd.exe` (если мне память не изменяет) и использовать их... Поведение задавать конфигурацией, для этого есть ConfigurationManager и ConfigSections

Comment: Может быть, какой-нибудь DI-framework умеет такое?